# How to export a weighted networkx graph to edge list in desired format?

Tags: python, networkx, edge-list

I'm trying to take a weighted networkx graph and convert it to an edgelist .txt file, where each row takes the form of three space-delimited numbers that indicate the starting node, ending node, and corresponding weight.

Here's what I've tried for a simple seven-node, weighted undirected graph:

```
 import networkx as nx
 import numpy as np
 A = np.matrix([[0,7,7,0,0],[7,0,6,0,0],[7,6,0,2,1],[0,0,2,0,4], 
 [0,0,1,4,0]])
 G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
 nx.write_edgelist(G, "weighted_test_edgelist.txt", delimiter=' ')
```

The text file is created and looks as follows:

```
0 1 {'weight': 7}

0 2 {'weight': 7}

1 2 {'weight': 6}

2 3 {'weight': 2}

2 4 {'weight': 1}

3 4 {'weight': 4}
```

However, I want the above to instead appear as

```
0 1 7

0 2 7

1 2 6

2 3 2

2 4 1

3 4 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
nx.write_edgelist(G, "weighted_test_edgelist.txt", delimiter=' ', data=['weight'])
```

Output:

```
0 1 7
0 2 7
1 2 6
2 3 2
2 4 1
3 4 4
```

Per docs:

> data : bool or list, optional    If False write no edge data.    If
>   True write a string representation of the edge data dictionary..    If
>   a list (or other iterable) is provided, write the  keys specified
>   in the list.